# Minecraft Survival Mode

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing Minecraft on survival mode. I can break blocks like sand, dirt, and gravel and it will give me a block. When I try to break stone or iron or anything else, it didn't give me a block. What can I do so that I can get a block? I am on single player and my internet is fine. I tried deleting the app and then getting the app again but that didn't work. This is happening with all my worlds in survival mode.

Comment: Are you using the proper tools to break blocks? You'll need a pick for stone, for example.

Comment: Yes. I'm using wooden weapons. But when I use them to break stone, it doesn't give me a block.

Comment: Weapons? You need to use a pickaxe. And read a wiki.

Comment: Try `/gamerule doTileDrops true`

Comment: @kingbluesapphire This is minecraft PE.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the tool requirements for mining blocks,

Wooden Pickaxe - Stone & Coal

Stone Pickaxe - Iron and above

Iron Pickaxe - Gold, Redstone, Diamond & above

Diamond Pickaxe - Obsidian & Above.

to get items like glass and Ice you need to enchant these with Silk touch(quite Rare)

Also you can get items like coal, redstone and diamond in more quantities per ore using a Fortune Pick (preferably Fortune 3)